# Example of Node.js Express registering Underscore.js as view engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, viewengine, underscore.js

Underscore.js does not have a compile function like ejs and jade, but does work as a Node.js module. Would someone please provide an example of how to make it work inside an Express app?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

app.register('.html', {
  compile: function (str, options) {
    var template = _.template(str);
    return function (locals) {
      return template(locals);
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: This is for express <3

Answer (score 4):

Now with express 3.0 , it's a bit different. Easy solution : 
https://github.com/haraldrudell/uinexpress

```
npm install uinexpress
```

then

```
app.configure(function () {
app.engine('html', require('uinexpress').__express)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
```